# Wait for TreeView is full expanded or ListViewItem is selected

Tags: c#, vb.net, listview, treeview, wait

I want to make screenshots by code during runtime.

The form, where is "shotted", consits of a treeview, a listview and some labels with textboxes. If somebody click on an treeviewnode, there will be some listviewitems in the listview. Foreach different listviewitem, some labels with their textboxes are shown. If somebody click on another treeviewnode or another listviewitem, then other labels with their textboxes will be shown. So, all is very dynamically. I worked with "AfterSelect" and "SelectedIndexChanged" to realize that.

So, now i want screenshots of all possibilties. To make a screenshot and save it - no problem. To Expand/Collapse or select some items - no problem. But how can I wait with the screenshot till all items, labels or textboxes are shown.

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) should be not the solution ;-) Something like "WaitForAllIsShown&NothingHappend" should be nice.

Thanks.

The current code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        trvDevice.CollapseAll()

        For Each node As TreeNode In trvDevice.Nodes 

            trvDevice.CollapseAll()
            trvDevice.SelectedNode = node
            trvDevice.SelectedNode.Expand()
            DoScreenshots(node.Text)

            For Each subnode As TreeNode In node.Nodes

                trvDevice.CollapseAll()
                trvDevice.SelectedNode = subnode
                trvDevice.SelectedNode.Expand()
                DoScreenshots(node.Text + "#" + subnode.Text)

                For Each item As ListViewItem In lsvCommands.Items 

                    lsvCommands.SelectedItems.Clear()
                    item.Selected = True
                    DoScreenshots(node.Text + "#" + subnode.Text + "#" + item.Text)

                Next
            Next
        Next

        DoScreenshots()

    End Sub
```

DoScreenhot(filename as string) is just the method to take the picture.

Comment: What API are you using? Is this WinForms or WPF? I am guessing the former, but you should be clear. Also, please be more specific about the problem. Is it that there's some animation you want to wait for? Or does the visual state change directly (without animation), but only after the `DoScreenshots()` method is called?

Comment: Sorry, i use VB.net in VS2013.

Comment: There is no animation, but the listview will be filled at runtime and a selection of some  labels/textboxes will be shown at runtime. I want that all things (Items filled and labels/textboxes shown) happend before i do "DoScreenhots()". But I don't know, how to wait. PS: I don't want to specific all controls (listview, label,textboxes) separat, the best will be something like "Wait-For-The-Complete-Form-Is-Loaded()"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a [solution](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?662742-Waiting-for-a-screen-re-draw-to-finish-before-continuing).

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

I put these at the first line of the "DoScreenshot()"-methode. All works fine.